# SpriteKit - Ignore transparency when selecting node

Tags: sprite-kit

I have an SKSpriteNode that has a texture assigned like this:

```
node.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Oval")
```

Users can select this object and drag it around. I use the following to identify when it is being selected in the **touchesMoved** function.

```
var touchedNode = allObjects.nodeAtPoint(location)
```

The problem is that almost half the surface area of this image file is transparent. However, **nodeAtPoint** responds to touches on the transparency.

Does anyone know of a way to ignore the transparency?

Comment: Just to be clear, it's 100% transparent, correct? It only takes something like 5% opaqueness to start receiving touches events. Also, did you verify that the node returned by nodeAtPoint is actually the node you're talking about and not a different one?

Comment: Hi @BenKane, Yes, the transparency is 100% and I can confirm that the correct node is being selected as I can drag it around by the transparent area of the image.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I seem to have found a duplicate of this question which includes screenshots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710880/handle-touch-events-in-skspritenodes-with-transparency

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your image please? I have a theory but would need to see your image.

Comment: Hi @BenKane, I have just uploaded the image.

Comment: Somewhat confirms my theory. I'm wondering if it takes the non-transparent area and makes a box from its furthest bounds. You could do some testing and check if that's the behavior SpriteKit is giving. That would explain why your tap and the one in the question you link to register in the transparent areas.

Comment: @BenKane Apparently not, I thought you might be right but no. I've just tested by drawing a small green box with a large transparent area around it and the transparency is selectable.

Comment: I think you'll have to use nodesAtPoint and loop through them and grab the one you'll need situationally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89430/discussion-between-sparked-and-ben-kane).

Comment: The only node at that point is the single one with the transparency, I'm afraid. Its all as one.

Comment: Chat man, click the chat link

Comment: what happens is  your frame will be a box that surrounds the non transparent data, and anything inside that box can be selectable from the node standpoint.   you have a few options you can go,  you can break up the image into smaller nodes that go inside the big node, and that can reduce the amount of allowable transparency,  or you can read the image data to determine if that point is transparent

Answer (score 1):

In your touches Moved you can get the color of the pixel of the node you touched and then using an if statement you can ignore the node if the color is transparent (has an alpha of 0). Check here to see how to get the color

[SpriteKit: How can I get the pixel color from a point in SKSpriteNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941784/spritekit-how-can-i-get-the-pixel-color-from-a-point-in-skspritenode)