# SpriteKit: How can I get the pixel color from a point in SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a maze game and i'm using a SKSpriteNode as the actual 2d maze.

I want to detect if the point on the SKSpriteNode a user is touching is black or white. I've made a UIImage which is the same image as the SKSpriteNode, and I'm using a method on the UIImage to get the pixel info. However, the UIImage seems offset compared to the SKSpriteNode. It's returning values as I move my finger around the screen, but it's incorrect. I'm guessing the UIImage is not the same size and position as the SKSpriteNode.

How can I fix this?

I use the following to get the pixel data

```
extension UIImage {
func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

    let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}
```

}

I've made my SKSpriteNode like this

```
var theColor : UIColor = UIColor()
var bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: mazeImageName)
var mazeMap : UIImage = UIImage(named: mazeImageName)!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    bgImage.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
    bgImage.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)

    self.addChild(bgImage)

}
```

And here is where I actually get the pixel color

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {

        theColor = (mazeMap.getPixelColor(touch.locationInNode(self)))

        var red : CGFloat = CGFloat()
        var green : CGFloat = CGFloat()
        var blue : CGFloat = CGFloat()
        var alpha : CGFloat = CGFloat()

        theColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        print("Red: \(red), Green: \(green), Blue: \(blue), Alpha: \(alpha)")

    }

}
```

Comment: _I want to detect if the point on the SKSpriteNode a user is touching is black or white._ Why not set `SKSpriteNode`'s `name` and determine black or white by its `name`?

Answer (score 1):

Is the size of your image the same size as your `SKScene`?

In `touchesBegan` function, Try getting the location of your touch inside `bgImage` instead of the `SKScene`.

```
theColor = (mazeMap.getPixelColor(touch.locationInNode(bgImage)))
```